# Which part of my previous post "is NOT properly formatted as code" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-formatting, quality-filter

Could anyone specify which part was wrong with my description in my previous post?

I've just asked a question on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553058/how-to-show-the-filenames-under-the-selected-folder-on-the-radio-button). In the process, I couldn't post my question because of the following error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I googled and found a solution that needs to put `<pre><code>` ... `</code></pre>` around the codes. My program has three blocks of codes, so I put `<pre><code>` ... `</code></pre>` each of them, but it didn't solve the problem. So, I started from scratch, pasting one code at a time. Those three codes didn't cause the problem. However, as soon as I put the following description, the "Your post appears to contain ..." message showed up again:

> Let's assume that there are three folders: FolderA contains
>   1_log.xlsx, 2_log.xlsx, 3_log.xlsx. FolderB contains 4_log.xlsx,
>   5_log.xlsx, 6_log.xlsx. FolderC contains 7_log.xlsx, 8_log.xlsx,
>   9_log.xlsx.
>
> In this case, 7_, 8_, 9_log.xlsx will be shown, even when FolderA is
>   selected. I expect to see 1_, 2_, 3_log.xlsx when I select FolderA on
>   the Radio Button.

... So, I surrounded the description with a Blockquote and was able to post my question.
What's wrong with my description? Does it look like a code???

Furthermore, I've just tested, putting my description **WITHOUT** a Blockquote here, but it didn't prevent me from posting. Rather, I've got:

> Your question is ready to publish! Our automated system checked for
>   ways to improve your question and found none.

... Does anyone know what was wrong with my previous post? I don't want to encounter this problem any more. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Please [read the formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (as advised).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thank you for your information. However, seriously, which part was wrong? Were the underscores in `7_, 8_, 9_` considered as _italicized_?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Please be more specific. Which one are you talking about, my codes or my description? For your info, I have indented my codes by four spaces using the code toolbar button since I started Stack Overflow and have had no problem ... until yesterday.

Comment: Automated systems are never 100% perfect, there will always be corner-cases where they won't work well. It seems that Stack Overflows post-checking system doesn't handle underscores well in non-code parts of the post.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, I agree, this system isn't perfect. I don't need such fancy formatting if it causes troubles to post a question. I think I have caused a stir enough, so I'll let administrators at Stack Overflow handle this.